# Where to store different iOS icons in Phonegap?

Tags: ios4, icons, cordova

I'm creating my various different icons for my PhoneGap app as outlined here:

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36905973/Icons-and-Splash-Screens

However, phonegap only seems to allow me to select icons for the launch screen and icon.

Where should icons such as the iPad icon (icon-72.png) be stored?

Thanks,
-gearoid.

Comment: It would seem as though yuo upload some icons when submitted your app to Apple (such as the 512x512) one. However, I'm still confused over where some icons (like the spotlight 50x50 icon) go.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following elements to config.xml

```
<icon src="icons/ios/icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="icons/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
```

For more details see https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml